Downloading a folder from cloud storage in GitHub action and move it inside a docker container is not working
My GitHub action
name: Deploy

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy: 
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: default
    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setup Node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 16

    - id: auth
      name: "Auth"
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
      with:
        token_format: access_token
        workload_identity_provider: ${{ secrets.WIF_PROVIDER }}
        service_account: ${{ secrets.SA_EMAIL }}

    - name: 'Set up Cloud SDK'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v2'
      with:
        version: '>= 363.0.0'
        
    - name: 'Use gcloud CLI'
      run: 'gcloud info'
      
    #- name: 'Last ned BASED model fra cloud bucket'
      #run: 'gcloud storage cp -r gs://mlops/model_llama_2 .'
    - name: Print file list 1
      run: |
          find . -type f -print | sort
#         find . -type d -print | sort

    - name: 'Last ned LORA fra cloud bucket'
      run: |
          mkdir fine_tuned_model
          gcloud storage cp -r gs://mlops/fine_tuned_lora fine_tuned_model/

    - name: Print file list 2
      run: |
          find . -type f -print | sort
#         find . -type d -print | sort

    - uses: docker/login-action@v3
      name: Login to Google Artifact Registry
      with:
        registry: europe-docker.pkg.dev
        username: oauth2accesstoken
        password: ${{ steps.auth.outputs.access_token }}
    
    - run: echo "TAG=$(git log -1 --pretty=%ad --date=format:%Y-%m-%d)-$(git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

    - uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
      with:
        file: Dockerfile
        push: true
        tags: europe-docker.pkg.dev/team2137/trygg/app:${{ env.TAG }}

#    - name: "deploy app til cloud run"
#      run: "gcloud run deploy <service-name> --image=<image-uri> --region=europe --allow-unauthenticated"

My docker file
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


COPY . .

CMD ["python", "app.py"]

My problem is the downloaded folder called fine_tuned_model is not being copied inside the docker container when docker finishes building. It copies everything else from GitHub but the downloaded folder from bucket. I have tried to even manually copy the dir in dockerfile with no luck!
As you can see I am also listing the dir files before and after step to see if it is being downloaded. And fine_tuned_model is being downloaded.

There are 2 types of context with build-push-action:

git
path

you are using git context, so any file mutation in the steps that precede the build step will be ignored. However, you can use the Path context using the context input alongside the actions/checkout action to remove this restriction.
